# Google Authentication to Google+ SignIn

Tags: windows-runtime, oauth-2.0, windows-phone-8.1, google-plus, google-oauth

I am building  **Windows Phone 8.1 (WINRT)** and implementing Google+SignIn with help of **WebAuthenticationBroker**.

I used to use old google API for getting Token:
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth

```
 String GoogleURL = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?client_id=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleClientID) + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleCallbackUrl) + "&response_type=code&scope=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleScope);
```

1. What is the replacement of this as if they are going to close Aouth in march 2015.

2: Also for this?
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code

```
var url = "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token?grant_type=authorization_code"
                + "&code=" + _authorizationCode
                + "&redirect_uri=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(GoogleCallbackUrl)
                + "&client_id=" + GoogleClientID
                + "&client_secret=" + _consumerSecretKey;
```

3: Also tell me  about **scopes** replacements

Answer (score 0):

Google is migrating away from the legacy OpenID 2.0 login **to** Google+Signin. See: https://developers.google.com/+/api/auth-migration. `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth` is not an "old" or deprecated API. You're already using the "new" stuff built on OAuth 2.0 so you're fine.